# Getting error as `Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance` - state not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update the state on `onClick` but getting error as :

`Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`

Not able to figureout the issue. any one help me?

here is my update function:

```
import { UPDATE_NAME } from "./Actions/types";
const initialState = {
  name: "Arif"
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_NAME:
      console.log("action.payload", action);
      return [...state, { name: action.payload }];
  }
  return state;
};

export default rootReducer;
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/52m9374zll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

> return [...state, { name: action.payload }];

use this

> return {...state,  name: action.payload };

or

> const payloadObj = {name: action.payload}
>
> return {...state,  ...payloadObj  };

Answer (score 0):

Your initial State is JSON object.

During first run of statement return [...state, { name: action.payload }];
It will work in following manner
...state => ... initialState => name: "Arif"
As you used it inside array therefore it's like -> [name:"Arif", {name: action.payload}] which is invalid.

You need to declare your initialState as following

```
const initialState = [
  {
     name: "Arif"
  }
];
```

Comment: so, we should supposed to use the map operator anyway?

Comment: Yes if your output is array (which was not in the case of initialState) you can use map function